# Throw error when user changes ID in the URL (Yii2 and PHP)

Tags: php, yii2

I am currently working on a program where a user can change his profile data, such as name and password ect. However, I want to limit the user to change the id in the url and then be able to look up some other users data.

For example, when user with the ID 1 wants to change his password, he uses the following url:
`http://localhost:8093/myapplication/web/index.php?r=user%2Fupdate&id=1`

Now I want to prevent user 1 to simply change the URL to
`http://localhost:8093/myapplication/web/index.php?r=user%2Fupdate&id=2`
and be able to manipulate the user with the said ID unless he is a admin of course. I have been using access rules to limit the access of non admin users to certain actions, however the non admin user must be able to change his own data as well.

This is what I have in the `UserController.php`:

```
**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return
        [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['update',],
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'allow' => Yii::$app->user->identity->admin,
                        'actions' => ['view', 'create', 'delete', 'index',],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }


public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        // Check if User is admin or not. If he is, allow every operation...
        if ($model->admin === true) {
            if ($this->request->isPost && $model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['update', 'id' => $model->iduser]);
            }
        }
        // ... If the User is not admin, he can't change the URL to another ID.
        elseif ($model->admin !== true) {
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

I have been looking up https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization to find an idea on how to actually manage it but I don't really get it. I am very new to Yii2 as a whole, so any help, advice and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the logged in person has that ID, if yes they can do it and if not, error.

```
if($model->id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id){
    //Change Something
}else{ 
    throw new ForbiddenHttpException(/*Here explanation if needed*/);
 }
```

I hope i can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time and your idea. How would you tackle the thing with the admin? The admin user needs to be able to change the id anytime.

Comment: You helped me a lot. I just made a mistake in the thought process. Works like a charm.

Comment: then u add in the if State `|| Yii::$app->user->can("admin")` or `|| ($model->admin==true) `

|| is the short version of OR